# Professional Apprenticeship as Work Experience for Express Entry

Tags: working-visas, canada, express-entry

While filling up the work experience section of the express entry profile I came across this sentence,

> Do not enter any work related to or performed during an apprenticeship
>   process.

I know for sure this includes the [apprenticeship done while being a student](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=394&top=29), but
I cannot understand if it also refers to the professional paid apprenticeships or not.

I have ~2.5 years of professional experience in Italy (out of which 2 years are full-time), on a work permit and paid. However, my work contract has a title like: Professional Apprenticeship (it's an Italian kind of contract). How can I determine if this work experience is eligible to be counted or not?

Comment: Don't quote me but as long as its an apprenticeship it cannot be considered as work experience.

Answer (score 3):

[CIC](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=394&top=29) answers this question very clearly.

> ### Can I count work experience that was part of my education toward the work requirement?
>
> No. Co-op terms and apprenticeships completed before graduating do not
>   count as skilled work experience. They are considered part of an
>   educational program.
>
> The work experience you can use to apply for the Canadian Experience
>   Class must not have been gained while studying full time on a student
>   permit (for example, experience gained while on a co-op work term).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reference but still I can't understand if professional apprenticeship (paid, full-time, after graduation) is counted or not, because here it is referring to the ones done before graduation.

Comment: I guess! If true it means my three years of work experience would go to trash! lol - anyway I'll try to contact them and will update here!